# Neo4j Cypher node filtering by pattern comprehension

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following SDN 4 entities:

`Decision`, `Characteristic` and `Value`:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Value extends Votable {

    private final static String SET_FOR = "SET_FOR";
    private final static String SET_ON = "SET_ON";
    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @Relationship(type = SET_FOR, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision decision;

    @Relationship(type = SET_ON, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Characteristic characteristic;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private Object value;

    ...
}
```

I have created 3 `Decicion`(`Decicion1`, `Decision2`, `Decisison3`) nodes and 1 `Characteristic`(`Characteristic1`).
For `Decicion1`, `Decicion2` and `Characteristic1` I have created a `Double` `Value`, for example:

```
Decision1 + Characteristic1 = Value(500d)
Decision2 + Characteristic1 = Value(1000d)
Decicion3 doesn't have any Value on Characteristic1
```

I need to create a query that will return all `Decision` which have `Value` in the defined range, for example `100 <= value <= 50000`

Based on the example above this query should return `Decision1` and `Decicion2` only.

Right now I have a following query:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
    WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
        AND ALL(key IN keys({rangeFilters}) 
            WHERE size(
                [(childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(filterValue)-[:SET_ON]->(filterCharacteristic) WHERE id(filterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND ({rangeFilters}[key])[0] <= filterValue.value <= ({rangeFilters}[key])[1] | 1]
            ) > 0)  
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

where `rangeFilters` is a `Map<String, Double[]>` where key is a `Characteristic` `ID` and value `new Double[] { new Double(100.d), new Double(50000d) }`

But this query returns all 3 `Decision`, even the `Decision3` that don't have any values associated with `Characteristic1` .

How to fix this query in order to return only `Decisions` that match a condition ?

**UPDATED**

This is an example that highlights the issue: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=6bv9y5

**UPDATED**

I'm tried to apply solution described by `Tezra`. This is my curent query:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(filterValue)-[:SET_ON]->(filterCharacteristic) 

WHERE  

ALL(key IN keys({equalFilters}) WHERE id(filterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND filterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[key]))  

AND  

ALL(key IN keys({rangeFilters}) WHERE id(filterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND ({rangeFilters}[key])[0] <= filterValue.value <= ({rangeFilters}[key])[1])  

RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

Unfortunately assertion in my tests fails on this query.

This query works fine only when I specify the single filter condition, for example:

```
ALL(key IN keys({equalFilters}) WHERE id(filterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND filterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[key]))
```

or

```
ALL(key IN keys({rangeFilters}) WHERE id(filterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND ({rangeFilters}[key])[0] <= filterValue.value <= ({rangeFilters}[key])[1])
```

but doesn't work when both of them are present. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you please update with a new minimal verifiable example for the new query? (And this probably REALLY should be a new question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example data, you just need to link all the checks correctly. (the parent stuff isn't in the example, but I think it was just the key-range part messing you up)

```
WITH {c1:[100,50000]} AS rangeFilters
MATCH (childD:Decision)<--(fv:FilterValue)-->(c:FilterCharacteristic) 
WHERE ALL(key IN keys(rangeFilters) 
    WHERE c.id=key AND rangeFilters[key][0] < fv.value < rangeFilters[key][1]) 
RETURN childD
```

Although you could also make FilterValue a relationship since relationships can have properties too.

UPDATE:

As for your problem with WHERE ALL( equals...) AND ALL(in_range...); That reads "Where all equal filters are true and all range filters are true". So I'm guessing that you actually want is any of them to be true which would be WHERE ANY (equals...) OR ANY(in_range) (available [predicates](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/)), as it is impossible for filter.value to equal 7 and 9 at the same time.

Also, as a side note, don't use id() in your queries, as Neo4j reserves the right to change those as much or little as it likes. Set your own id fields, and use a UUID instead. A UUID is also much more reliable if you need to merge data sets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the example provided in my question is only the part of the big picture. So I'm interested in the approach described at my question.

Comment: @alexanoid fixed to use range key part.

Comment: thanks. I tried to apply your solution with a partial success. I have updated my question with a details. In general the query works only on a single filter condition and doesn't work when present a multiple of them.

Comment: @alexanoid I updated the answer to address your new problem.

Comment: thanks, but it is something not I'm expecting. I have applied 2 filters with a conditions for a different values for different characteristics. So I'm trying to find all nodes(decisions) that have Characteristic1.value in some range and Characteristic2.value equals to some value.

Comment: @alexanoid as your query stands, you are testing each characteristic.value as being both equal, and in range (and if you set more than one equal case, they can't all be true). If you are doing tests on 2 different nodes that both need to be true, you need to pull the second characteristic node out into its own variable, defining how it is related to the other nodes in the set. So to help you further, I need you to say what you are looking for in plain English (what are all the conditions you want to be true).

Comment: This question was about the filter part (which is answered) so you might want to formulate how to build the actual query in another question (referencing this question in the continuation question).

Comment: "filtering by pattern comprehension" - there is a possible issue with an approach based on pattern comprehension and filtering. Right now it is not clear why it doesn't work with an original solution based on pattern comprehension

Comment: @alexanoid by "explain in plain English" I meant "say in English the exact pattern you are trying to match". As far as I can tell, your "filtering by pattern comprehension" is just a complex pattern match, and I can tell your query is wrong, but I don't know how to make it right without knowing the exact pattern that has to be matched. This is getting a bit long for comments so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143883/discussion-between-tezra-and-alexanoid).

Comment: The issue described at this question starts from this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824894/neo4j-cypher-query-structure-and-performance-optimization It was an attempt to optimize this ugly and non effective query into something more efficient. Right now there is a theoretical solution how to implement it based on "pattern comprehension" approach and maps. This solution theoretically can reduce the current data cardinality in ~10 times and significantly improve the performance. Right now it is not clear why this approach doesn't work as expected

Comment: Thanks for your answer in the separate question. One question - is it possible to implement this with the approach from this question ?

Comment: @alexanoid I would replace the WHERE ALL (....) with WHERE ({rangeFilters}[filterValue.id])[0] <= filterValue.value <= ({rangeFilters}[filterValue.id])[1]), so that you only check the relevant key for each filter. However, this is just an alternative way of defining the range values. I don't think it will affect performance. You can run PROFILE though on both versions to see if it makes a difference. (If I had to guess, the map lookup might be insignificantly slower due to the extra lookup step, but than you can 'import' filters in your query.

Comment: It fails with Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.CastSupport$.castOrFail(CastSupport.scala:43)

Comment: @alexanoid Yeay, no. I take it back. Don't use a map lookup when you can just do a direct check. The map lookup requires pulling up far more nodes.

Comment: after each MATCH you have to get the cardinality down again, e.g with  `WITH distinct childD`

Comment: will do it but I can't get it even working on the "map" approach. As I have described at my question - it is only working for a single condition.. but not for 2 or more combined with "AND"

Comment: I started new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908077/neo4j-cypher-filtering-based-on-map-parameters