# Neo4j Cypher filtering based on map parameters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Based on the previous question:

[Neo4j Cypher query structure and performance optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824894/neo4j-cypher-query-structure-and-performance-optimization)
[Neo4j Cypher node filtering by pattern comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855265/neo4j-cypher-node-filtering-by-pattern-comprehension)

finally I have refactored my query to the following:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
    WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
        MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(equalFilterValue)-[:SET_ON]->(equalFilterCharacteristic) 
            WHERE ALL(key IN keys({equalFilters}) WHERE id(equalFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND equalFilterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[key]))  
    WITH DISTINCT childD  
        MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(rangeFilterValue)-[:SET_ON]->(rangeFilterCharacteristic) 
            WHERE ALL(key IN keys({rangeFilters}) WHERE id(rangeFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND ({rangeFilters}[key])[0] <= rangeFilterValue.value <= ({rangeFilters}[key])[1]) 
WITH * MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)  
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

This query works fine if each `*filter` type(map) has only one key, for example:

```
queries.add(new InQuery(integerCharacteristic.getId(), 30));
```

or

```
queries.add(new InQuery(stringCharacteristic.getId(), "Two"));
```

but fails when I add 2 or more conditions, for example:

```
queries.add(new InQuery(integerCharacteristic.getId(), 30));
queries.add(new InQuery(stringCharacteristic.getId(), "Two"));
```

The following query doesn't work as expected and my test assertions fail:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
    MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(inFilterValue)-[:SET_ON]->(inFilterCharacteristic) 
        WHERE ALL(key IN keys({inFilters}) WHERE id(inFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) AND ({inFilters}[key]) IN inFilterValue.value) 
WITH * MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)  
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

The parameter:

```
inFilters = {3153=30, 3151=Two}
```

Why it doesn't work when `inFilters` map contains 2 or more keys and how to make it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the reason this only works with 1 key, lets go over what one WHERE ALL is doing when there is 2 keys.

```
WITH inFilters = {3153=30, 3151=Two}
....
WHERE ALL(key IN keys({equalFilters}) 
    WHERE id(equalFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(key) 
    AND equalFilterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[key]))
```

Is equivalent to

```
WHERE id(equalFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(3153) 
AND equalFilterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[3153]) 
AND id(equalFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(3151) 
AND equalFilterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[3151])
```

And the problem there is that now we are checking that the node id of equalFilterCharacteristic is equal to 3153 AND 3151 at the same time, for each and every equalFilterCharacteristic. Since Neo4j only uses real numbers for the node ids, the above statement basically ends up reducing to an expensive WHERE FALSE when there is more than 1 key. So WHERE ALL can never be true in the above case. WHERE ANY however will evaluate to true if at least 1 check-group is true, and would be equivalent to

```
WHERE ( 
    id(equalFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(3153) 
    AND equalFilterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[3153]) 
)
OR 
(
    id(equalFilterCharacteristic) = toInt(3151) 
    AND equalFilterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[3151]) 
)
```

Of course, since you know the key you are trying to match, you can skip the ALL and just do (don't think you need toInt() on id(), but id() is a long)

```
WHERE equalFilterValue.value = ({equalFilters}[id(equalFilterCharacteristic)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in other words - there is no way to implement such logic in a such way and I have to stick with an original approach from the following ticket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824894/neo4j-cypher-query-structure-and-performance-optimization?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: @alexanoid Sort of... The key here (pun unintended) is the node lookup part. Using only the map check, you have to go through every node, check if they id is a key in the map, and check the value. If you pull up the nodes like (psudocode) id(node) IN map.keyset(), than you no longer have to pull every node for the map[node.id] exists check. Cypher is a descriptive language though, so hiding things in a map makes it harder for Cypher to plan a more efficient query. So a map will never quite be equivalent to another query format. (except when you do a full loop over it)